# Web Audio live streaming

Tags: audio, streaming, audio-streaming, web-audio-api, media-source

There is an audio stream which sends from mobile device to the server. And server sends chunks of data (due web-sockets) to the web.
The question is. What to use to play this audio in live mode, also there is should be a possibility to rewind audio back, listen to what was before..and again switch to live mode.

I considered such possibilities as Media Source API but it's not supported by Safari and Chrome on IOS, isn't it?  But we need that support.

Also, there is Web Audio API which supports by modern browsers, but I'm not sure does it possible to listen to audio in live mode and rewind audio back?

Any ideas or guides on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

> I considered such possibilities as Media Source API but it's not supported by Safari and Chrome on IOS, isn't it? But we need that support.

Then, you can't use MediaSource Extensions.  Thanks Apple!

> And server sends chunks of data (due web-sockets) to the web.

Without MediaSource Extensions, you have no way of using this data from a web socket connection.  (Unless it's PCM, or you're decoding it to PCM, in which case you could use the Web Audio API, but this is totally impractical, inefficient, and not something you should pursue.)

You have to change how you're streaming.  You have a few choices:

## Best Option: HLS

If you switch to HLS, you'll get the compatibility you need, as well as the ability to go back in time and what not.  This is what you should do.

## Mediocre Option: HTTP Progressive

This is a fine way to stream for most use cases but there isn't any built-in way to handle the stream seeking that you want.  You'd have to build it, which is not worth your time since you could just use HLS.

## Even More Mediocre Option:  WebRTC

You could switch to WebRTC for streaming, but you have greatly increased infrastructure costs and complexity.  And, you still need to figure out how you're going to handle seeking.  The only reason you'd want to go the WebRTC route is if you absolutely needed the lowest latency.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sir, as we need the lowest latency I see the best option, for now, is WebRTC

Comment: @TarasKulchytskyi You could also use a blended approach, where WebRTC is used for live but you switch back to HLS for going back in time.  That would allow you to use the most off-the-shelf components.

Comment: WebRTC will not allow you to pause and rewind. In my opinion, the best option for your requirements is still MediaSource extensions. Pretty low latency and ability to pause and rewind. And it is supported on iPads, to correct Brad's answer. No iPhones though, yet. This is the kind of player you need: http://umediaserver.net/umediaserver/demohtml5MSEplayer.html

Comment: @user1390208 thank you for info regarding webRTC, but support for iPhones must have , hard decision what to use for support all modern browsers

Comment: @TarasKulchytskyi Safari is anything but a modern browser, by design.  In any case, as I said, if you use multiple protocols, your problems are solved.